# Return to onActivityResult after SMS send

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult, android-sms

I would like to have a SMS intent be populated for the user, then launch the intent and after the SMS is sent, return to my app to continue to execute code. So thus far I use this to setup the Intent:

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + cellNumberEditText.getText().toString());
 Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
 smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", smsMessageEditText.getText().toString());
 smsIntent.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true);
 startActivityForResult(smsIntent,1);
```

Note I add the Extra `exit_on_sent` parameter to the intent.

Then off course I catch the `onActivityResult`:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1)
    {
        //Do some post sending work
    }
}
```

The problem is, after debugging, I noticed that as soon as the intent launches, the `onActivityResult` fires immediately, not after the the intent closes. Furthermore, the SMS app does not close after sending even though the parameter is set. I even added `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` to my Manifest.xml. What am I missing?

Comment: Hope this one will help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26091732/3632609)

Answer (score -1):

You should add `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);` and `finish();` in the requested activity. The latest return back to the requester activity.

Comment: How can I do that? The SMS intent I launch is closed off from my side, i cannot change the code it uses? If I had launched an activity I created myself that would have been possible

Comment: i've found this way:
`String number = "12346556";  // The number on which you want to send SMS  
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromParts("sms", number, null))); `